# Getting a attr inside stylable via XML

Tags: android, xml, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have a few TextViews in my custom view. And I want them to take style from the theme. To do this, I refer to the custom `labelTextAppearance` attribute:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:textAppearance="?attr/labelTextAppearance" />
```

If I declare `labelTextAppearance` at the theme level everything works wonderfully:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="labelTextAppearance">@style/SavageWorldsTextAppearance.Label</item>
</style>
```

But I want to be able to declare a style for all custom views through one property. Just like `Button` via `butonStyle`. To do this, I created a new attribute `paramViewStyle`, in which my textAppearance's are enumerated:

```
<style name="Widget.AppTheme.ParamView.Custom">
        <item name="valueTextAppearance">@style/SavageWorldsTextAppearance.DefaultValue</item>
        <item name="defaultValueTextAppearance">@style/SavageWorldsTextAppearance.DefaultValue</item>
        <item name="labelTextAppearance">@style/SavageWorldsTextAppearance.Label</item>
</style>
```

Then I specify `paramViewStyle` in the application theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="paramViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ParamView.Custom</item>
</style>
```

But TextView's can't catch up that the attributes are now in paramViewStyle.

How can I tell TextView through xml that the parameters they are interested in are inside another attribute?

**UPD**: This is my theme-level attributes:

```
<declare-styleable name="ParamViewTheme">
    <!-- ParamsView default style. -->
    <attr name="paramViewStyle" format="reference"/>

    <attr name="valueTextAppearance" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="defaultValueTextAppearance" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="labelTextAppearance" format="reference"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you need to declare all the different appearances in a `declare-styleable` which you then can refer in your style.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Already do this (check my question upd). I am looking for a way to retrive this appearances from `TextView`s inside my custom view xml via `?attr/...`. I think it should looks like `?attr/paramViewStyle/valueTextAppearance`

Comment: I think you need something like that `<declare-styleable name="ParamViewTheme">
    <attr name="paramViewStyle" format="reference">
      <enum name="valueTextAppearance" value="valueTextAppearance"/>
      <enum name="defaultValueTextAppearance" value="defaultValueTextAppearance"/>
      <enum name="labelTextAppearance" value="labelTextAppearance"/>
    </attr>
  </declare-styleable>`